# How to hide other widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

When the text is focus the other widget will be hide for example
[When the texfield focused is false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwAks.png)

[When the textfield focused is true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W43sc.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Visibility widget to show or hide widgets.

> [Visibility](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html) widget, which can hide a child more efficiently
> (albeit less subtly, because it is either visible or hidden, rather
> than allowing fractional opacity values).

There are a couple other widgets like the Opacity widget or offstage widget that you may try :

> [Opacity](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html) widget, which can stop its child from being painted.
>
> [Offstage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Offstage-class.html) widget, which can stop its child from being laid out or
> painted.